# Reading input from getchar

Tags: c++, c, getchar, getch, putchar

```
while(1)
{
    if(i == 6)
        break;
    temp[i] = getchar();
    putchar(temp[i]);
    i++;
}
```

Whenever i had to use getchar in this way, it accepts enter also as one of the input and thus I am restrained to enter only three characters instead of 6. Why getchar takes enter as one of the input? How to avoid this?

Input:

```
1
2
3
```

After this loop breaks because the three returns pressed are considered as three inputs to temp[1], temp[3] and temp[5].

Answer (score 9):

`getchar` reads a character at a time. On pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> key you are passing newline character `\n` to the C standard buffer, which is also read by `getchar` on next call of `getchar`. To avoid this `\n` character you can try this

```
while(1)
{
    if(i == 6)
        break;
    if((temp[i] = getchar()) != '\n')
    {
        putchar(temp[i]);
        i++;
    }
}
```

Also read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17309619/2455888) to know how `getchar` works.

Comment: Ah, 6 upvotes? Did anyone actually compile and run the code? The loop will break beforce print 6 char on the screen too if the user input a char one time.

Comment: @haccks yes as WKplus said it will break before which i dont want because input is one char per line

Comment: @WKPlus; Admitting that. Edited now.

Answer (score 5):

Check for white space character and don't add/count it. getchar() returns all characters you hit including new lines and spaces.

```
while(i < 6)
{
    temp[i] = getchar();
    if (isspace(temp[i]))
        continue;

    putchar(temp[i]);
    i++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`getchar` reads one character at a time from the `stdin` buffer. once you are entering a character and pressing Enter then in `stdin` buffer two characters are getting stored.

if you want to enter six character by using your code then enter all characters at once and then press enter it will work. otherwise you will have to skip 'Enter' character. like this...

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
        int i=0;
        char temp[10];
        while(1)
        {
                if(i == 6)
                        break;
                temp[i] = getchar();
                if(temp[i]!='\n')
                {
                        putchar(temp[i]);
                        i++;
                }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why `getchar` takes enter as one of the input?

The character input functions read input from a stream one character at a time. When called, each of these functions returns the next character in the stream, or `EOF` if the end of the file has been reached or an error has occurred.
Some character input functions are buffered (Example: `getchar()`). This means that the operating system holds all characters in a temporary storage space until we press <kbd>Enter</kbd> , and then the system sends the characters to the `stdin` stream.

How to avoid this?
As suggested by [haccks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20741376/1814023)

Answer (score 0):

how about this method.You can use getchar() two twice.
Like this,

```
while(1)
{
    if(i == 6)
        break;
    temp[i] = getchar();
    getchar();
    putchar(temp[i]);
    i++;
}
```